# Expression for a bad photograph

Tags: expressions, adjectives

What are the most common　(informal) expressions for a badly taken photo?

My first guess was 悪い写真, but searching for that in google finds only scary pictures, so I don't think that it's what I'm searching for.

My other guesses are:

- 気持ち悪い写真
- 上手くない写真

Comment: Technically flawed or "I'm looking ugly"-style?

Comment: The actual sentence I wanted to say was this cheesy line: "There's no way a photo of you can turn out bad."

Comment: @Chris "There's no way a photo of you can turn out bad.">>「君の写真がキレイに撮れないはずないさ」とかですかね・・・「君がキレイに写らないわけないだろう？」とか。。。？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [下手{へた}な写真](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E4%B8%8B%E6%89%8B%E3%81%AA%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F)
  The straight-forward way of saying 上手くない写真. Used when the bad photo is the photographer's fault.
- [ダメな写真](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%83%80%E3%83%A1%E3%81%AA%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F)
  Basically the same as 下手な写真, but can also refer to photos that are unacceptable for a specific purpose, like a passport.
- [写りの悪い写真](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%86%99%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AE%E6%82%AA%E3%81%84%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F)
  This is usually (but not always) about photos with people in them. If there is a nuance of implying whose “fault” it is, it is mostly poking fun at or self-deprecating of the person *in the photo*, rather than the photographer who took it. 写真写りが悪い = unphotogenic.

Answer (score 1):

「気持ち悪い」means gross, disgusting, so better to not use the word if you don't mean to purposely insult the person, or if you don't mean the photo is gross.

上手くない写真 sounds better. Other might be うまく撮られてない写真.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a bad photo will be 写りの悪い写真